# Can't get $.ajax call to work when processing form

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery [bootstrapValidator](http://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrapValidator/) plugin to validate a form and process a form.  The validation seems to be working but the ajax call inside of the submitHandler doesn't work.  To simplify I put the php file in the same directory as the contact form and have it just echoing back a message.

When you hit the submit button nothing happens the page just reloads.

Here is the html:

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="contact-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class=" control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" />

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" />  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Phone </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" />
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up">Submit</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$('#form').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    live: 'enabled',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

         //alert("made it to submit handler block!");

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "process.php",
          data: $('#form').serialize(),
          success: function(msg){

              alert("made it to success block!");
              alert(msg);

          },
          error: function(){
            alert("We found an error in your data.  Please return to home page and try again.");
          }
        });//close ajax
    },
    fields: {
        firstName: {

            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
        lastName: {

            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
    } // end field
});// bootstrapValidator
```

Here is a demo
http://aaronhaas.com/waterford/contact.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Try to replace `submitHandler` with `onSuccess`

Comment: There are examples of how to submit the form using ajax in the docs for the plugin: http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/

Comment: Thanks!  That got it into ajax block, but the I received an error from the error function so it didn't make it to the php which is just :echo "made it to php"; Am I using the right variables for the ajax data field?

Comment: the checkboxes in your code is interrupting. if you select 'chemical' and submit your success message is being displayed.

Comment: I removed all of the fields on the form except the two name fields and I'm still getting the same error which tells me the ajax call is not making it to the php

Comment: i tried on the website it is working i am getting the message from the success block as well as from the php file.